# debounceTime() not callable from service class

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Can someone explain why `debounceTime()` is not `callable` from `service` class. I created a service out of `fromEvent` observable which I `subscribe` to, the aim was to reduce code repetition but I get this error.

[image: debounceTime()]

**DebounceSearchService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class DebounceSearchService {

    constructor() { }

    search(input: HTMLInputElement, debounceTime: number) {
        return fromEvent(input, 'keyup').pipe(
            debounceTime(2000),

            // get value
            map((event: any) => { return event.target.value;})

            // if character length greater then 2
            , filter(res => res.length > 2)

            // If previous query is diffent from current   
            , distinctUntilChanged()

            // subscribe for response
            , 
    );
}

}
```

I did lookup other answers, but not sure and there was no clear answer to this.

Comment: Is it imported? What `debounceTime` is it?

Comment: Can you also show your imports in service file in the code snippet?

Comment: `debounceTime ` is imported. Added code snippet for imports also.

Comment: what version rxjs used?

Comment: @AntonMarinenko `"rxjs": "^6.6.7"`, debounceTime doesn't throw error outside service class.

Comment: is your build shows any error?

Comment: What is the actual error when you hover over the red squirly?

Comment: Thanks everyone, actually it was conflict of second argument. Tried renaming once but my compiler didn't resolve it until I rebuild and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `search` function second argument. It is also called the same reserved name of the `RxJs` operator `debounceTime`. That should fix it for you. Your argument name can be `debounceTimeXYZ`.

Comment: It's stupid, never realised it could be this! my compiler didn't show error after i renamed it. Spent much time on this error, renaming and rebuilding fixed it.